# Is it possible to pass variables to CSS file in Django

Tags: css, django, django-views

I was wondering is it possible to pass a variable from a Django view to CSS file? Is there any way?
I was following some tutorials in a front end design and wondered if it can be built dynamically in Django?

```
.card:nth-child(1) svg circle:nth-child(2){
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * 90) / 100);
  stroke: #00ff43;
}

.card:nth-child(2) svg circle:nth-child(2){
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * 80) / 100);
  stroke: #00a1ff;
}

.card:nth-child(3) svg circle:nth-child(2){
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * 60) / 100);
  stroke: #ff04f7;
}
```

```
stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * {{ var }}) / 100);
```

can i pass those variables from a view to this var in CSS?
this portion of code gives 90, 80 and 60% respectively. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your variable in you css if the css is in your `<head>`, like :

```
<head>
  <style>
  .card:nth-child(1) svg circle:nth-child(2){
    stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * {{ var }}) / 100);
    stroke: #00ff43;
  }
  </style>
</head>
```

But you can not pass it directly to your external css file.

In the case, you have a **base.html**:

```
<head>
  {% bloc extra_style %}
  {% endblock %}
</head>
```

And in you template:

```
  {% bloc extra_style %}
  <style>
  .card:nth-child(1) svg circle:nth-child(2){
    stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * {{ var }}) / 100);
    stroke: #00ff43;
  }
  </style>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ok but then how would I render two templates i.e. base.html and index.html ?

Comment: I have update my answer following you question, take a look, hope it helps.